# Service Class not being instantiated during @Autowire call

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-boot, stomp

I am attempting to use a @Service class in my messaging application, however the class is not instantiated via @Autowire when I try from a generic class. It is only instantiated when I use the Controller.

Here is my controller:

```
    package hello;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping;
import org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.SendTo;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageSendingOperations;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

import hello.Application;

@Controller
public class HelloController {


    @Autowired
    private MessageSender sender;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }

    @MessageMapping("/hello")
    @SendTo("/topic/greetings")
    public Greeting greeting(HelloMessage message) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Sending message...");
        beginRoute(message.getName());
        sender.greet("thunder");
        return new Greeting("Hello, " + message.getName() + "!");
    }

    public void beginRoute(String message) {
        Application.startBody(message);
    }
}
```

The above call to sender.greet is successful.

Here is the other class I attempt to use the service in:

```
package com.routing.integration;

import hello.*;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessageSendingOperations;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;


@Component
public class modifier {

    @Autowired
    private MessageSender sender;

    public boolean adder(String words) throws Exception {

        sender.greet(words);
    }
}
```

When I attempt to call sender.greet as above, I get a NullPointerException and when debugging, I find that sender is null at the time of the call to sender.greet. Is the service class not instantiating in modifier?

Finally, here is the MessageSender service class:

```
@Service
public class MessageSender {

    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate template;


    @RequestMapping(value="/hello", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public void greet(String greeting) {
        Greeting text = new  Greeting("Goodbye, " + greeting + "!");
        this.template.convertAndSend("/topic/greetings", text);
    }

}
```

How can I ensure that @Autowire instantiates the MessageSender in every class?

**EDIT**

Here is where the call to modifier is made. It is made from a camel route:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:core="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/osgi http://camel.apache.org/schema/osgi/camel-osgi.xsd
    http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd
    http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

<route>
        <from uri="activemq:queue:testQSource"/>

        <choice>
            <when>
                <method ref="securityBean"/>
                <log message="Routing message from testQSource to testQDestination queue with data ${body}"/>

                <to uri="activemq:queue:testQDestination"/>
                <to uri="activationBean"/>
                <to uri="accountVerificationBean"/>
                <to uri="billingCheckingBean"/>
                <to uri="deviceConnectorBean"/>
                <to uri="deviceActivatorBean"/>
                <log message="Account activated: ${body}"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                <log message="message went to stomp: ${body}"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
</route>
</camelContext>


<camel:camelContext id="camel-client">
    <camel:template id="camelTemplate" />
</camel:camelContext>

<bean id="activemq" class="org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent">
    <property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://localhost:61616" />
</bean>
<bean id="browserBean" class="hello.HelloController"/>
<bean id="securityBean" class="com.routing.integration.modifier"/>
<bean id="activationBean" class="com.routing.integration.ActionApp"/>
<bean id="accountVerificationBean" class="com.routing.integration.AccountVerifier"/>
<bean id="billingCheckingBean" class="com.routing.integration.BillingChecker"/>
<bean id="deviceConnectorBean" class="com.routing.integration.DeviceConnector"/>
<bean id="deviceActivatorBean" class="com.routing.integration.DeviceActivator"/>

</beans>
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
Stacktrace
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    ------------------------------------------------
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.routing.integration.modifier.adder(modifier.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:278)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:251)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:67)
at     org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression$InvokeProcessor.process(BeanExpression.java:1    89)
at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:123)
at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.matches(BeanExpression.java:137)
at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:90)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:    72)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
at     org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.ja    va:103)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(Abstract    MessageListenerContainer.java:562)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMe    ssageListenerContainer.java:500)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(Abstrac    tMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecut    e(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(    AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoke    r.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoke    r.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1094)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoke    r.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:991)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
WARN : org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener - Execution of JMS     message     listener failed. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException -         java.lang.NullPointerException]
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapRuntimeCamelException(ObjectHelper.java:1363)
at     org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener$EndpointMessageListenerAsyncCallback    .done(EndpointMessageListener.java:186)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.ja    va:107)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(Abstract    MessageListenerContainer.java:562)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMe    ssageListenerContainer.java:500)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(Abstrac    tMessageListenerContainer.java:468)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecut    e(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:325)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(    AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:263)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoke    r.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1102)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoke    r.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1094)
at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoke    r.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:991)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.routing.integration.modifier.adder(modifier.java:19)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:407)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.doProceed(MethodInfo.java:278)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.MethodInfo$1.proceed(MethodInfo.java:251)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:166)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
at org.apache.camel.component.bean.BeanProcessor.process(BeanProcessor.java:67)
at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression$InvokeProcessor.process(BeanExpression.java:1    89)
at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.evaluate(BeanExpression.java:123)
at org.apache.camel.language.bean.BeanExpression.matches(BeanExpression.java:137)
at org.apache.camel.processor.ChoiceProcessor.process(ChoiceProcessor.java:90)
at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:    72)
at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:398)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:191)
at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:105)
at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:87)
at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.ja    va:103)
... 11 more
```

**EDIT 2**

Here is my main class that calls ComponentScan:

```
package hello;

import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"hello", "com.routing.integration"})
public class Application {
    static ApplicationContext context = null;
    static ProducerTemplate camelTemplate = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        System.out.println("----------------------\nSpringBootComplete\n----------------------");
        startBody("startup");
    }

    public static void startBody(String message) {
        if (context == null) {
            context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("camelspring.xml");
            camelTemplate = context.getBean("camelTemplate", ProducerTemplate.class);
        }
        if (message != "startup"){
            camelTemplate.sendBody("activemq:queue:testQSource", message);
        }
    }           
}
```

Comment: Is your package com.routing.integration included in the component scanning? I see that package for `modifier` class is different from everything else. Also, please don't name your classes like that...

Comment: Are you using `new modifier()` somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback! I've made an edit that shows where the call to the modifier is made. It is through a camel route and is instantiated by a bean in the route. @dimoniy, sorry about the class names... How would I include the com.routing.integration in the component scanning? @chrylis, I don't think I use `new modifier()` anywhere, would that make a difference?

Comment: If the autowiring works just for controllers this means that the autowiring mechanism happens just for the app context for the `DispatcherServlet`. If you have `context:annotation-config` only in your xml file for the `DispatcherServlet` try putting the same `context:annotation-config` in the root xml, as well (the one defined for `contextConfigLocation` parameter), and see how it goes.

Comment: I'm using Spring boot so I don't have a web.xml, which xml file would I find this in? I have an app-context.xml, but it only has `<context:component-scan base-package="com.routing.integration, hello"/>` in it. Where should I be finding or putting `context:annotation-config`?

Comment: Hm, how do you use that `app-context.xml`? Also, you need to provide the main app class. I'm more interested, especially in all your `@ComponentScan`s you might have on your classes.

Comment: I don't think that I reference it in my code anywhere. I have posted the main app class, which is the only place I use `@ComponentScan`. Should I be using it elsewhere?

Comment: Why are you manually creating a `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`? This is the reason why it's not working. How could the app contexts created by Spring Boot know of your manually created app context.

Comment: If you cannot get rid of that xml (by using Java Config style of configuration), consider using `@ImportResource` annotation. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java-combining-java-centric) details about how to use it.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! Would you mind explaining what you mean by "getting rid of the xml" and how I would do it "using Java Config style configuration"? And would I reference the app-context.xml with the `@ImportResource`?

Comment: Also, you don't need all those `<bean />` definitions. Using `@ComponentScan` everything that has certain annotations (`@Component`, `@Service` etc) will be picked up automatically and used. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-stereotype-annotations) more about this.

Comment: "getting rid of the xml" means the definitions you see in that xml could be translated into Java code. See [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-java) more details. I strongly suggest reading the reference documentation for Spring, it is very good and has a lot of good info in there. You seem to be missing the basics of both Spring Boot and Spring itself.

Comment: Okay, so I understand what you're saying about getting rid of the xml, however I'm not sure how to replace the use of my ClassPathXmlApplicationContext element because I use it to initiate my camel route. Basically, how do I create my context without it?

Comment: Spring Boot creates its own application contexts. And that controller you have issues with was created in Spring Boot's app context. So, when you test your app and bring it up in a browser you see what Spring Boot offers you from the app contexts it creates. You, on the other hand, are creating your own app context. The contexts Boot creates and that you create cannot communicate one with each other to exchange info on what beans one has and what beans the other has. Also, Spring Boot apps are not meant to be built like you tried to. Do, please, go over the documentation I suggested.

Comment: We need that entire XML file with the Camel routes. Is it a Spring context file?

Comment: I've updated the question with the entire XML file. Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: @Andrei, I've been reading the documentation but I'm not sure how to include my camel route if I don't use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Comment: If I use @ImportResource("camelSpring.xml"), how can I reference the camel context or route from my application?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `Application` class should look like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"hello", "com.routing.integration"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ImportResource("classpath:camel.xml")
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Where `camel.xml` is the xml configuration file that contains your camel definitions.
If you need any of the beans defined in the xml configuration, like `camelTemplate` in your xml, you can get a reference of it like this, for example:

```
package hello;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.apache.camel.ProducerTemplate;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Resource(name="camelTemplate")
    private ProducerTemplate template;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    String home() {
        System.out.println(template);
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

As I said in the comments, don't create an app context manually. Register the beans you want with `@Component`, `@Service`, `@Configuration` and `@Bean` etc. If you need xml configuration that is difficult to reproduce in Java code, use `@ImportResource`.

In the xml config file you have, you can replace `browserBean` bean with a `@Controller` annotation placed on the `hello.HelloController` class.

Your `activemq` bean could translate to something like this in Java Config:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {

    @Bean
    public ActiveMQComponent activemq() {
        ActiveMQComponent comp = new ActiveMQComponent();
        comp.setBrokerUrl("tcp://localhost:61616");

        return comp;
    }
}
```